# How to correctly use Context::Scope ?

Tags: v8

How to correctly use Context::Scope ? Do i allocate it while within a method/function scope while actually executing something or can i have a global copy of it next to the Context object ? The documentation isn't very clear on that.
I want to make a global Application class and keep all the persistent stuff there not sure if i can put context scope there.

Answer (score 0):

`Context::Scope` has to be allocated on the call stack outside of your call chain. What you want to do is use a `Persistent<Context>` to store your `Context` object globally, and then create a `Context::Scope` when you enter a JavaScript call stack.  This is the case for all of V8's scope objects (`HandleScope`, `Isolate::Scope`, etc.).