# Weird C++ syntax: type definition before a function call

Tags: c++, syntax

I was reading NodeJS and V8 source, particulary `node_contextify.cc` file, and I could not understand the following line:

```
Context::Scope context_scope(debug_context);
```

I don't understand what is that `Context::Scope` before what seems to be a function call. I don't think it is a declaration because it is a function code, together with an `if` and other calls.

Complete relevant code:

```
...
    if (debug_context.IsEmpty()) {
        // [... lines removed for brevity ...]
    }
    Context::Scope context_scope(debug_context);
    MaybeLocal<Script> script = Script::Compile(debug_context, script_source);
    if (script.IsEmpty())
        return;  // Exception pending.
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(script.ToLocalChecked()->Run());
}
...
```

**What is the meaning of that `Context::Scope`?**

---

Further information:

File: [node/node_contextify.cc](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/f7842ad1698984e978bc414bc359cb5268b953d9/src/node_contextify.cc#L268) (the line 268 is highlighted).

While I understand it is a basic question about syntax, I don't even know how to call it, so I was not able to find any result in Google, StackOverflow or C++ reference.

The question title is one of my attempts when searching for it.

Comment: It's namespace. Scope is a type defined inside namespace Context. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace for more information.

Comment: You're looking for the [`scope resolution operator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b451xz31.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, Ken and Wong! I knew about namespaces, but not about this kind of initialization. @jdigital have answered it =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's initializing the context_scope variable with debug_context.  Context::Scope is the type (here's one ref page http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1Context_1_1Scope.html)

Here's another article on using Context::Scope [How to correctly use Context::Scope ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842018/how-to-correctly-use-contextscope)

BTW, even if you don't know what to call it, searching for "v8 Context::Scope" will turn up information.

Comment: Thank you! With your help I have found a lot about it =) . I don't know how to add related questions, but I think the part about the syntax is similar to [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764831/c-object-without-new).

Comment: Yes, the code is initializing an object on the stack.

Answer (score 3):

```
Context::Scope context_scope(debug_context);
```

You are declaring an object `context_scope` of type `Context::Scope` and initializing it with `debug_context`
`Context::Scope` could be a type defined in a class or struct, for example:

```
class Context {
public:
    using Scope = int;
    ....
}
```

or, `Context::Scope` could be a type defined inside a namespace, such as:

```
namespace Context {
    using Scope = int;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you too! However, the accepted answer suits my case better with the additional information provided. Anyway, I clicked +1 for you, but my ranking is low and the +1 is not visible publicly =/

Comment: Understand, and I appreciate your response :)